# mod_pagespeed - fetching images and css under session scope

Tags: apache, tomcat, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Is there a way to configure mod_pagespeed so that it can fetch contents that are under the session scope ?

In my case the resources mapping logic resides in the tomcat layer and hence all the images are under the session scope.

Since when pagespeed tries to fetch the resource and since it does not have a session - I think its getting redirected to the login page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ignore these kinds of resources if they are session-specific. mod_pagespeed is all about caching at the server-level, so it doesn't sound like it's appropriate to use in these cases.

Comment: I understand that. Almost all the resources are outside but some are still inside the webapp. Is it possible to fetch these resources via mo_pagespeed ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to map them properly: only map truly-static resources through mod_pagespeed.